# CSS: hide overflow content into bootstrap btn-group

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

For example i have table:

```css
/* Styles go here */
    
    table.my {
      width: 600px;
    }
    
    table.my > tr {
      height: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .tag {
      background: #b8b8b8;
      padding: 4px;
      color: blue;
    }
    
    .tag-area{
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .name {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover my">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              <span class="name">Ammy Holdings</span>
              <div class="tag-area">
                <span class="tag">iOS</span>
                <span class="tag">PM</span>
                <span class="tag">Android</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>
              <span class="name">Ken Martins</span>
              <div class="tag-area">
                <span class="tag">PM</span>
                <span class="tag">CTO</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>
              <span class="name">Ammy Holdings</span>
              <div class="tag-area">
                <span class="tag">iOS</span>
                <span class="tag">PM</span>
                <span class="tag">Android</span>
                <span class="tag">CEO</span>
                <span class="tag">Sale</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and it look so:

[image]

as you can see: overflow tags are situated wrong...
but i can't put them into my table with such dimensions, and i need to put overflowed content into group, like this:

[image]

and i have not any ideas, how to do that.
Maybe SO community can give me some ideas? How to put overflow content into `button group` (bootstrap)?

you could check style and **plunker** here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5qSDb6BGvskS0iwncZdi?p=preview

btw: i'm using angularjs in real app...

Answer (score 0):

In your Code include **Bootstrap** it will solve your problem and will result same like plunk which is you provided..

```css
/* Styles go here */
    
    table.my {
      width: 600px;
    }
    
    table.my > tr {
      height: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .tag {
      background: #b8b8b8;
      padding: 4px;
      color: blue;
    }
    
    .tag-area{
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .name {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover my">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <span class="name">Ammy Holdings</span>
      <div class="tag-area">
        <span class="tag">iOS</span>
        <span class="tag">PM</span>
        <span class="tag">Android</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <span class="name">Ken Martins</span>
      <div class="tag-area">
        <span class="tag">PM</span>
        <span class="tag">CTO</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <span class="name">Ammy Holdings</span>
      <div class="tag-area">
        <span class="tag">iOS</span>
        <span class="tag">PM</span>
        <span class="tag">Android</span>
        <span class="tag">CEO</span>
        <span class="tag">Sale</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <h4>Must be</h4>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover my">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <span class="name">Ammy Holdings</span>
      <div class="tag-area">
        <span class="tag">iOS</span>
        <span class="tag">PM</span>
        <span class="tag">Android</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <span class="name">Ken Martins</span>
      <div class="tag-area">
        <span class="tag">PM</span>
        <span class="tag">CTO</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <span class="name">Ammy Holdings</span>
      <div class="tag-area">
        <span class="tag">iOS</span>
        <span class="tag">PM</span>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <em>...</em>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Android</li>
            <li>CEO</li>
            <li>Sale</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
```